# After ruby update to 2.5.0, require 'bundler/setup' raise exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

Call `rake` from rails app after ruby 2.5.0 update, does not work.

```
$ rake
Traceback (most recent call last):
    22: from ./bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
    21: from ./bin/rake:4:in `require_relative'
    20: from /Users/user/work/hw/relocations_app/config/boot.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    18: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    17: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    16: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
    14: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
    13: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
    12: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
    11: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
    10: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
     9: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:247:in `resolve'
     8: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:806:in `converge_locked_specs'
     7: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:874:in `expand_dependencies'
     6: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:874:in `each'
     5: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:887:in `block in expand_dependencies'
     4: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:887:in `each'
     3: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:888:in `block (2 levels) in expand_dependencies'
     2: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
     1: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/dep_proxy (LoadError)
```

config/boot.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)

require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
```

`bundler/setup` can not be required.

A same problem is with passenger, to start rails app with that:

```
Error ID: 309814d3
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-yCUWSg.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /var/www/vhosts/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  /var/www/vhosts/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:456:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:323:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:461:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:322:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Have anybody a same problem with ruby 2.5.0?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Fix is simple: update RubyGems min up to 2.7.4 version

```
gem update --system
```

[RubyGems 2.7.4 includes bug fixes.](http://blog.rubygems.org/2017/12/25/2.7.4-released.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem has returned. See https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8978.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the only solution here is to upgrade Bundler to >= 1.16.1. See https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/pull/738 for an example where this is fixed in theory, but is blocked by Heroku unfortunately.

Upgrade to Bundler 1.16.1+ and you won't have any more issues.